# Is it posible if i wanna to make paginate not limit in cakephp in other words i want show all data as conditions

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0

I am using paginate in cakephp 2, 
I have created the page in paginator,

but I have trouble when i want to show all data,
because paginate make the data limit, i want the data is limitless or all datas,

this is my code paginate set conditions and limit,

```
$this->paginate = array(
                'conditions'    => $conditions,
                'limit'         => 20,
            );
```

and the data when i print, start from 0 and end at 19, it means the paginate limit setting is running,

then I have created other statement which the data must be show all like the conditions,

this is the code,

```
$this->paginate = array(
                        'conditions'    => $conditions,
                    //    'limit'  => 20
                    );
```

I just make the paginate setting as conditions, I comment the limit setting, but the data also show 20,

I have tried to change the code like this,

```
$this->paginate = array(
                        'conditions'    => $conditions,
                        'limit'     => 100,
                        'maxLimit'  => 10000
                    );
```

the data show 100,

how I can show all data without I make limit and maxLimit, or how I can show all data with conditions but not automatic limit (20 data)

because I am do not know the data total,
somebody can help me ?

thanks before..

Comment: i am not sure about it but you can read this [http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2011/02/28/cakephp-how-to-show-all-records-options-while-still-using-paginate/]

Comment: i already that posting, but not answer T_T

Comment: what if you give `'limit' => 12345678912345678`

Comment: This makes no sense at all. Why would you use *paginate* if you want to display *all* any way...?

Comment: i also thought this at first but may be he want to use limit and then in `if { }` condition he want to use unlimited

Comment: @Vky : i already try to make the limit is 1234677888... it's successfully but i think can make unlimited without make limit 1234677888

Comment: @burzum : I want make print page and print all, so i make 2 conditions in controller , first conditions for page, and second is for all..

Comment: @Vky : Thank you Vky for your help to tell..

Comment: This *will* blow up sooner or later depending on the amount of retrieved data from the DB and the available memory.

Comment: @burzum : so, how much data can I show in my "Print All" Menu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to fetch all records but you can try either one of the following lines:

```
$all = $this->ModelName->find('count', array('conditions'=> $conditions));
```

Or try:

```
$alldata = $this->ModelName->find('all', array('conditions'=> $conditions, 'limit' => $all));
```

This will fetch all records from tables and you can manage it in view according to your need.

Comment: Your code is running correctly.. but For your information, I using paginator, so for count the data I'm not search data again, but use the paginator count data, $this->request->params['paging']['Model']['count'].. thanks...

Comment: In case of using paginator, you can pas the limit in paginate like this:

$this->paginate = array(
                        'conditions'    => $conditions,
                       'limit'  => $all
                    );

Comment: $this->paginate = array( 'conditions' => $conditions, 'limit' => $this->request->params['paging']['Model']['count']); this is what i mean, I'm not search data but I use the paginator count with request params..